# How do I set the default value in my form on page load? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to set the default value of my form field, but I'm not sure where I can pass in that information. Here's what I have so far:

```
def month_options
  [["JAN", "01"], ["FEB", "02"], ["MAR", "03"], ["APR", "04"], ["MAY", "05"], ["JUN", "06"], ["JUL", "07"], ["AUG", "08"], ["SEP", "09"], ["OCT", "10"], ["NOV", "11"], ["DEC", "12"]]
end
```

In my view, I'm using this:

```erb
<%= select_tag :month, options_for_select(month_options, params[:month]) %>
```

I'd like to be able to set the default value of my form field to the current month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
<%= select_tag :month, options_for_select(month_options, params[:month] || "JAN") %>
```

...if you want the selected value to default to "Jan" of `params[:month]` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the selected option like this:

```
:selected => params[:default_value]
```

You can pass a parameter, string, etc whatever your case may be.

Comment: I believe this is for the form builder select tag (i.e. `f.select...`) not `select_tag`